# Unable to filter specific properties from ADSI direct reports search

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

For the past few days i have been trying to get specific properties (Name, Title, etc.) from an ADSI search of someones direct reports with no luck. Here is my current code:

```
$searcher = [adsisearcher]"(samaccountname=$user)"
$DirectReports = $searcher.FindAll().Properties.directreports
```

So far, i have tried

```
$searcher = [adsisearcher]"(samaccountname=$user)"
$dr  = [adsi]('LDAP://' + $searcher.FindAll().Properties.directreports)
$drfinal = $dr.name
```

This returns nothing of course since was just trying to grab a name, so i am not sure how to narrow it down, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
$dr  = [adsi]('LDAP://' + $searcher.FindAll().Properties.directreports)
```

is not going to work, since `directreports` is a collection of DN entries.

Put it in a loop instead:

```
foreach($DirectReportDN in $searcher.FindAll().Properties.directreports){
    $DirectReport = [adsi]"LDAP://$DirectReportDN"
    # Now do $DirectReport.Properties.Name etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $user -Properties DirectReports | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DirectReports
```